# Using get count with if statment

Tags: arcpy

Pretty simple question though I am struggling with how to operationalize this, I want to rename a shapefile based on the number of features it contains. My initial thoughts are that I would need to create a list of the shapefiles contained in a folder, for those shapefiles use arcpy.GetCount and where count >= X rename the shapefile. I used an if statement followed by arcpy.rename and it managed to rename all the shapefiles. Thanks for your help with this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, this is a pretty straightforward script.

```
import arcpy, os

folder = ""
arcpy.env.workspace = folder

num = 50

for shp in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
   count = int(arpcy.GetCount_management(shp)[0])

   if count >= num
      base, ext = os.path.splitext(shp)
      #Append _ and the number of features in the shapefile to filename
      arcpy.Rename_management(shp, "{0}_{1}{2}".format(base, count, ext))
```

Edit: You might not have been able to get it work because `GetCount_management()` returns a result object that you can either get the value from with indexing (used here) or `.getOutput(0)`. In order to be compared to another number, it needs to be cast to `int`, since the output is a `string`.

Comment: Thansk again @Paul, that was all I needed to do was cast as int.